# Angular CLI and auto-refresh

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I work with the Angular CLI and when I run "ng serve" the project is supposed to refresh automatically. However, sometimes, it's not perfect. Sometimes, changes are not refreshed automatically and sometimes it does. When changes are not refreshed, I have to re-run 'ng serve' which wastes a lot of time.

Do you have any way to know in what cases changes are refreshed automatically and when they are not? Also, if I see that I have to re-run 'ng serve', is there any faster way to refresh the project?

Answer (score 11):

I was having the same issue, Angular CLI AutoCompile was not working, I used this command which resolved the issue

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

It may help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Which version of the CLI are you using? There was a bug in one of the betas where when it set up your project, it did not include a devDependency `(@ngtools/webpack)`. That caused an issue where the Typescript compiler wasn't picking up changes to your code, and as a result the refresh wasn't triggered.

I'm pretty sure that issue is now resolved, but depending on when you generated your project, you may still have an invalid `package.json`. My advice is to update the CLI as per their instructions, generate a new dummy project, and compare your existing project's configuration with their own and update as needed.

Answer (score 0):

This helps me

```
echo 65536 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

Answer (score -1):

You can open Developer Tool of Browser > chose tab Network> chose check book "Disable cache"

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
ng serve --poll=1000
```

From: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1610

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference. I'm sure there's some helpful context in that GitHub issue that can be summarized here.